# Getting error msg at runtime 'Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue'

Tags: vb.net

I have a clickonce application written in VB in 2015 VS and when someone clicks on the .exe I send them for the first time they get the msg "An Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue..."

If the user clicks continue then closes and restarts the application they no longer get this msg. But for how long I dont know. I say that because I managed to see where it is happening in my code after running it multiple times perfectly fine then the odd time.. i see the exception. So its not consistent and is confusing me.

Here is the code that it happens on:

`Dim UpfileNames As Object = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(spath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "DR087*.OLD")`

spath is a link to a 'share' folder  set up in IIS on our network server that is stored as a key
in our web service's web.config file.  key="FileLocationSharePath" value="\erdtd4587\DataStorage"

Here is the exception info I get when in VS when the exception actually occurs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146500602
  Message=Invalid Signature.

  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
       at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
       at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
       at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindPaths(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, String wildCard)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindFilesOrDirectories(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards, Collection`1 Results)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindFilesOrDirectories(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.GetFiles(String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards)
       at APRS.frmReportViewer.frmReportViewer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Working\APRS-SASR\APRS4.9\APRSApplication\Forms\frmReportViewer.vb:line 29
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

and here is the info it provides when actually running the exe and getting the msg..

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

 

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: Invalid Signature.

 

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindPaths(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, String wildCard)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindFilesOrDirectories(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards, Collection`1 Results)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.FindFilesOrDirectories(FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory, String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.GetFiles(String directory, SearchOption searchType, String[] wildcards)
   at APRS.frmReportViewer.frmReportViewer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

 


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4614.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
APRS
    Assembly Version: 4.9.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.9.0.0
    CodeBase: file://hrdc-drhc.net/Sites/NC/ESDC_DSL/RMS%20inbox/SRU%20R85407%20-%20APRS%20Desktop%20v4.9/APRS.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Web.Services
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Web.Services/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4605.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4550.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4584.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4621.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 14.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

 

For example:

 

    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
    </configuration>

 

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I havent tried anything to fix it as I wanted to research it and ask here beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

**How To: Debug your own code**

That function [FileSystem.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfiles?view=net-7.0)

```vb
Dim UpfileNames As Object = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(spath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "DR087*.OLD")
```

returns a [ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=net-7.0), so you shouldn't assign it to an Object. First of all, change your code to

```vb
Dim UpfileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(spath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "DR087*.OLD")
```

to allow implicit typing. Now you will have something you can use properly.

Now for your issue, check what exceptions [GetFiles(String, SearchOption, String[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfiles?view=net-7.0#microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-filesystem-getfiles(system-string-microsoft-visualbasic-fileio-searchoption-system-string())) may raise

> **Exceptions**
>
> **ArgumentException**
>
> The path is not valid for one of the following reasons: it is a zero-length string; it contains only white space; it contains invalid characters; or it is a device path (starts with \.).
>
> **ArgumentNullException**
>
> `directory` is Nothing.
>
> **DirectoryNotFoundException**
>
> The directory to search does not exist.
>
> **IOException**
>
> directory points to an existing file.
>
> **PathTooLongException**
>
> The path exceeds the system-defined maximum length.
>
> **NotSupportedException**
>
> A file or directory name in the path contains a colon (:) or is in an invalid format.
>
> **SecurityException**
>
> The user lacks necessary permissions to view the path.
>
> **UnauthorizedAccessException**
>
> The user lacks necessary permissions.

Checking your error message

> ... ************** Exception Text **************
>
> System.IO.IOException: Invalid Signature.

the matching one from the documentation is

> IOException
>
> `directory` points to an existing file.

Directory shouldn't be a file if you are looking for a directory. You should figure out why it's a file path instead of a directory path (debug your code). To do this, add an exception handler which handles the specific exception you're seeing, and break, and inspect the runtime variables.

```vb
Try
    Dim UpfileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(spath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "DR087*.OLD")
Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"'{spath}' points to an existing file. ") ' breakpoint here
End Try
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response and help. I am a confused by "Directory shouldn't be a file if you are looking for a directory". spath contains the path, its a share path, so im not sure what 'directory shouldnt be a file" And thanks for the other insights into not using Object and implicit casting etc.

Comment: I just thought of something... the webservice that is returning the list of files is actually on the same server as the file folder that contains these files... im using the share path when I should be using the actual directory since it has access to it. I wonder if this is causing this intermittent issues to show up because im forcing it to go thru IIS to access the directory through the share path.

Comment: @johnnyjojo I am only basing it on the documentation `IOException` `directory points to an existing file.` Did you debug it?